# Sync Vagrant folder in Windows with VirtualBox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows, synced-folder

I don't understand the answers that I can find to this, so I'll try to ask it again. I'm using Vagrant on a virtual machine using VirtualBox. My host machine has Windows 10.

According to https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html i should edit the Vagrantfile to contain `config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/srv/website"`. In understand the second parameter without any problem (the one on the guest machine).

I have two questions:

1: If my Vagrantfile is in C:\Users\mabj\Documents\vagrant\test2 and my folder that I want to sync is in C:\Users\mabj\Documents\code\test2, what should I write in the first parameter (host machine)?

2: Using Windows and VirtualBox, do I have to add any optional parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) config.vm.synced_folder "../../code/test2", "/synced_folder"

*from VM synced folder will be /synced_folder

(2) no